# Is DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(string providerName) expensive?

Tags: performance, ado.net

I'm trying to figure out if DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(string providerName) is expensive, or if I can safely create a new instance every time I need one.

The reason for this is that I have a situation where the provider name can change and it would be more convenient just to recreate the factory every time if that's a cheap call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expensive is a relative term.

Getting the Factory itself does not involve making a connection over the network, so from my vantage point it is inexpensive, even if there is a small amount of reflection behind the scenes.

Comment: Of course it's relative, but sometimes there's a definitive answer from the original programmers. For example, in the Entity Framework, it's expensive to load an object context the first time around.